# I'm trying to delete an object from an array and the response I get is that the data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, multidimensional-array, json-server

Im new in coding and faceing some problems and need some help I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this.
First Im using react.js for bilding my app and
I made a fake rest api using npm json.server. Every step in the code is working but not the  method DELETE and dont manage to remove the object from the array.
In my VS terminal i get a 404 response like this  `DELETE /albums/undefined 404`.
So i think it's not managing to see the data in the array.

the delete method looks like this:

```
const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3500/albums/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.json);
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          return;
        } else {
          setUsers(
            albums &&
              albums.filter((album) => {
                return album.id !== id;
              })
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    // console.log(data);
  };
```

Now I can post my complete function
this is my function:

```
import "./App.css";
import AddUser from "./components/adduser/AddUser";
import User from "./components/users/User";

const App = () => {
  const [albums, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [genres, setGen] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchGenres();
  }, []);

const fetchData = async () => {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3500/albums")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          console.log("everthing is OK!");
        } else {
          console.log("Somethig went wrong");
        }
        return res;
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setUsers(data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

const fetchGenres = async () => {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3500/genres")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          console.log("everthing is OK!");
        } else {
          console.log("Somethig went wrong");
        }
        return res;
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((value) => setGen(value))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

const onAdd = async (name, band, city, genresId) => {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3500/albums", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        band: band,
        city: city,
        genresId: parseInt(genresId),
      }),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.method);
        if (res.status !== 201) {
          return;
        } else {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setUsers((albums) => [data, ...albums]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3500/albums/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.json);
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          return;
        } else {
          setUsers(
            albums &&
              albums.filter((album) => {
                return album.id !== id;
              })
          );
          console.log(res.album);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Bands Albums & Genres</h3>
      <br />
      <AddUser onAdd={onAdd} values={genres} />

      <div>
        {albums &&
          albums.map((album) => (
            <User
              name={album.name}
              band={album.band}
              city={album.city}
              genresId={
                genres &&
                genres.map((g) => {
                  if (g.id === album.genresId) {
                    return g.name;
                  }
                  return "";
                })
              }
              onDelete={onDelete}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

My array structure looks like this:

```
{
  "albums":[
   {
      "name": "albumName1",
      "band": "BandName1",
      "city": "City",
      "id": 0,
      "genresId": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "albumName2",
      "band": "BandName2",
      "city": "City",
      "id": 1,
      "genresId": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "albumName3",
      "band": "BandName3",
      "city": "City",
      "id": 2,
      "genresId": 3
    }
],
"genres": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "grunge"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "rock"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "jazz"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "pop"
    },
  ]
}
```

this is the component that I'm using for render:

```
const User = ({ id, name, band, city, genresId, onDelete }) => {
  const handleDelete = () => {
    onDelete(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="list">
      <span>{name}</span>
      <span>{band}</span>
      <span>{city}</span>
      <span>{genresId}</span>

      <span>
        <button onClick={handleDelete}>delete</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have some more components in the function but I dont think that they have any influence in what i'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are not passing `id` prop to the `<User />` component.

Try this

```
           <User
              name={album.name}
              band={album.band}
              city={album.city}
              id={album.id}               <----- Add this line
              genresId={
                genres &&
                genres.map((g) => {
                  if (g.id === album.genresId) {
                    return g.name;
                  }
                  return "";
                })
              }
              onDelete={onDelete}
            />
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied. Thank you

Comment: @Nilo I mean click on the green tick icon to mark my answer, but thank you for upvote also :)

Answer (score 0):

console log what is `id` from `onDelete` function and you will see that it is `undefined`. That's why endpoint `/albums/undefined` is called.

```js
return (
    ...
    onDelete={onDelete} // the problem is here
    ...
);
```

further reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback